# Error Handling in Python3 (os.system)

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, os.system, try-catch-finally

In Python, I am calling sub files from main python file.
In all sub python files, I have included try and except block.
In main file, I need the sub files to be executed in the order I have mentioned below.
Is there a way to stop executing `os.system("python SubFile2.py")` statement, if any error is caught in `os.system("python SubFile1.py")` statement?
And also I need to get the error details in the main python file.

This is the code snippet of main file:

```
import os
import sys

print("start here")
try:
    print('inside try')
    os.system("python SubFile1.py")
    os.system("python SubFile2.py")
    os.system("python SubFile4.py")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:")
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    print(sys.exc_info()[1])
    print(sys.exc_info()[2])
finally:
    print('finally ended')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want your main process to be exited as well when an error encounters in x subfile?

Comment: yes main process should be exited

Comment: Ok, Please check my answer then. You should consider using `subprocess` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `[subprocess][1]` It's not recommended to use `os.system` if you want to catch the exception and end another process, Because `os.system()` indicates a failure through the exit code of the method. For more detail you should consider reading this answer: [Python try block does not catch os.system exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373563/python-try-block-does-not-catch-os-system-exceptions)

For your workaround, you can try this code which works, however I have used subprocess.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

print("start here")



files = ["first.py", "second.py"]
count=0
for file in files:

    try:

        cmd = subprocess.Popen(["python", file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = cmd.communicate()

        if(error):
            print(error)
            sys.exit()
    except OSError as e: 
        print("inside exception", e)
        sys.exit()
    count+=1
```